# Titanium Appcelerator compilation: slow or normal?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I'm compiling a very simple Titanium app (15 rows source code) for Android on my development laptop (Win 7 64bit w/ 8 GB RAM).

I'm using Titanium 3.4 GA SDK & Studio and I have connected my physical Nexus 5 to the PC.

From the moment I click the "Run as -> Nexus 5" option I have to wait 
1 minute and 20 seconds
for the compilation and the deployment on my physical device.

Deployment to the Nexus is made in just a few seconds, most of the time is spent on compilation (apk generation&signing, etc.) ...

Is that timing normal when developing with Titanium?

If not, any tips to speed the compilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use TiShadow, it will reload the app with your changes in just a couple of seconds:

$ npm install -g tishadow

then build with e.g.:

$ titanium build -p android -T device --shadow

That's enough to get you started, [check the docs](http://tishadow.yydigital.com/getting%20started) for what else you can do with it

Comment: for beginners, watch these tutorials about tishadow:  
  
http://www.dunkelgames.com/tutorials/tutorial-build-for-all-your-devices-at-once-with-tishadow-and-sublime-text  
   
http://olivalabs.com/2013/10/tishadow-for-titanium-development-part-i/

Comment: After connecting the tishadow server to the tishadow client app, just enter the project folder (command line window) and run:
tishadow run

Answer (score 0):

Additonaly  for Android development  you can use  GenyMotion